# Qt transparent label doesn't always update its background

Tags: qt, background, transparent, libvlc, qlabel

I have 3 child widgets of the main widget which are aimed to play video files(their sizes and positions are the same, I mean they are overlaying each other and at a time one of them is shown and others are hidden)

I also have a Qlabel with a transparent background that I created as a child of main widget as well. I raised this label in order to be shown over 3 video player widgets all the time. The code part of Qlabel is below:

```
labelCamName = new QLabel(this);
labelCamName->resize(300,50);
labelCamName->move(110,0);

labelCamName->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0%);color: rgba(150, 30, 30, 90%)");

labelCamName->setText("blabla");
labelCamName->raise();
labelCamName->show();
```

It works fine when the first video player widget that the label has been overlayed update itself(playing a video) but when it comes to change the widget playing video and show another widget to be played(not playing yet) that it shows a stationary black frame, the background of the label shows the last frame of the first video player widget. It doesn't pretend like it is a label with transparent backgroud, as shown by screenshots below:

[image: first video Widget]

[image: second video player widget]

Any suggestion why Im facing this issue and how to make the label work always transparent?

Thanks in advance. Very appreciated.

Comment: Which Qt version are you using? Depending on the kind and complexity of the UI behind these buttons, this UI would probably easier to implement in QtQuick, with better performance (compositing video and overlays using OpenGL).

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I'm using QT4 but can this problem really be related with version? I think I'm doing something wrong or forgetting to add some attributes.

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld, but nevertheless, this problem is interesting. In pic 2 the button clearly still shows the background from pic 1. Transparency is faked, by blitting the underlying widget on the background of the label. Looks like the label did not notice that the underlying widget changed. I wonder if this changes, when the second video is played.

Comment: @Horizon1710, I suppose you already tried to send an 'update' or 'repaint' to your label?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Yes I already tried them but didn't resolve. And no, it continues to do this weird thing also when second video is played. I realise something. I am using LibVLC on the second video player widget and noticed that it only happens on this widget. maybe you know or not, libVlc handles the widget by getting its WinID and uses the widget to render the frames. I strongly suppose libVLC causes it but don't know how to solve.

Comment: This could explain it. Of course, VLC has its own draw routines, it draws directly on the widget. I doubt that Qt's paint routines and events are in anyway involved in this. And it is not the desktop window under the label... so X11 is also not involved in any updates. A bit of speculation here, but a plausible one.

Comment: @Greenflow This weirdness seems to be caused by LibVLC drawing limitations, as this thread says: https://github.com/vlc-qt/vlc-qt/issues/33 .

I found a simple work around for this problem as I mentioned on my own answer. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding these attribute and flag to the desired Qlabel solved my problem.

```
labelCamName->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
labelCamName->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
```